# mysql insert query executed 2 times after add s3 put object aws upload image

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, sql-insert

i have problem when i want to upload image to aws using putObject. the image uploaded successfully but the problem is my mysql insert query executed 2 times so i get duplicate data. dont know why. but if i delete putObject code, the insert query works fine (just execute 1 time)

this is my php code

```
<?php

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
include_once "koneksi.php";

require '../awss3/vendor/autoload.php';

$config = require('../awss3/app/config.php');

$s3 = S3Client::factory([
  'key' => $config['s3']['key'],
  'secret' => $config['s3']['secret']
  ]);

class emp{}


$image = $_POST['image'];

$name = $_POST['filename'];

$actualpath = $_POST['path'];

$uploader = $_POST['uploader'];

$receiver = $_POST['receiver'];

    $path = "../solusight_ss/".$name."";
    $save1 = "".$uploader."/".$name."";
    $save2 = "".$receiver."/".$name."";

    file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));

    $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
                'Key' => "{$uploader}/{$name}",
                'Body' => fopen($path, 'rb'),
                'ACL' => 'public-read'
            ]);

    $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
                'Key' => "{$receiver}/{$name}",
                'Body' => fopen($path, 'rb'),
                'ACL' => 'public-read'
            ]);

            //Remove the file
            unlink($path);


    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbimage (filename, path, uploader,receiver, status,category,folder)
                    VALUES ('$name', '$save1','$uploader','$receiver', 0,'Photo',0)");
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbimage (filename, path, uploader,receiver, status,category,folder)
                    VALUES ('$name', '$save2','$uploader','$receiver', 0,'Photo',0)");

    if ($query && $query2){

        $response = new emp();

        $response->success = 1;

        $response->message = "Sending Picture..";

        die(json_encode($response));

    } else{

        $response = new emp();

        $response->success = 0;

        $response->message = "Error Upload image";

        die(json_encode($response));

    }


mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

NOTE : this is my server side code for my android application

Comment: Not familiar with AWS api, but as you are calling  $s3->putObject([]) twice, have you tried to insert all your data at the same time and only "push" it once? The "key" tag seems to be the only difference, yet you seem to call putObject twice. Is it a possibility to insert receiver data during first push?

Comment: oh yea actually i already tried just calling $s3->putObject([]) one time but the problem is same. except i delete $s3->putObject([]) then anything works fine

Comment: Just to clear up, are you getting the duplicate of the data itself or just your SQL? You do two separate insert data -queries after all, once again the only difference is sender vs. receiver. If you have auto-increment ID fields or similar, you will get two accounts of your upload. Is that meant to happen? (Any specific reason not to save sender/receiver information into same table at the same time?)

Comment: just my sql data was duplicate. because i store the image to different path defined by id user (uploader and receiver). because of that i set value for path with $save1 and $save2. and as a result, i get 4 new row (2 new row for each query)

Comment: If that is indeed the case, to my eyes it looks like the problem lies on some other part of code from where you call this upload script. I would suggest you php echo something from each part of the code so you can actually follow and see what part gets called twice?

Comment: ok let me try. thanks for advice :)